# MSQL: How to get 0 count instead of 1 and null with join tables or views

Tags: mysql

I tried to count data from joined views but giving wrong result.

**Queries Table (Main Table)**

```
+----+----------------------+---------+
| id | title                | history |
+----+----------------------+---------+
|  1 | test search title 2  |       0 |
|  2 | test search title 3  |       1 |
|  3 | test search title 4  |       0 |
|  4 | test search title 5  |       1 |
|  5 | test search title 6  |       0 |
|  6 | test search title 7  |       0 |
|  7 | test search title 8  |       1 |
|  8 | test search title 9  |       0 |
|  9 | test search title 10 |       1 |
+----+----------------------+---------+
```

**Results Table**

```
+------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|  id  | query_id |    published_at     |  status  |
+------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|    1 |       2  | 2017-11-27 12:00:56 | negative |
|    2 |       5  | 2017-12-20 16:17:42 | positive |
|    3 |       6  | 2017-12-20 16:20:22 | positive |
|    4 |       8  | 2017-12-20 16:28:26 | negative |
|    5 |       7  | 2017-12-20 16:29:48 | neutral  |
+------+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

I created 4 views to count data by day and status from `results` table

**Daily Total results**

```
CREATE VIEW v_results_daily_total AS (
           SELECT query_id, DATE(published_at) as day, 
            COUNT(*) as total FROM results
            GROUP BY query_id, day)
```

**Daily Positive results**

```
CREATE VIEW v_sentiment_daily_positive AS (
           SELECT query_id, DATE(published_at) as day, 
            COUNT(*) as pos FROM results
            WHERE status='positive'
            GROUP BY query_id, day)
```

**Daily Negative results**

```
CREATE VIEW v_sentiment_daily_negative AS (
               SELECT query_id, DATE(published_at) as day, 
                COUNT(*) as neg FROM results
                WHERE status='negative'
                GROUP BY query_id, day)
```

**Daily Neutral results**

```
CREATE VIEW v_sentiment_daily_neutral AS (
               SELECT query_id, DATE(published_at) as day, 
                COUNT(*) as neg FROM results
                WHERE status='neutral'
                GROUP BY query_id, day)
```

When trying to run the following query it's showing wrong counts.

```
select
  q.id,
  q.title,
  vt.day,
  vt.total as total,
  vp.pos as pos,
  vn.neg as neg,
  ve.neu as neu

from queries q
  left join v_results_daily_total vt on vt.query_id=q.id
  LEFT join v_sentiment_daily_positive vp on vp.query_id=q.id
  LEFT join v_sentiment_daily_negative vn on vn.query_id=q.id
  LEFT join v_sentiment_daily_neutral ve on ve.query_id=q.id
WHERE q.history=0
GROUP BY q.id,vt.day;
```

**Wrong results**

```
+----+----------------------+------------+-------+------+------+------+
| id | title                |    day     | total | pos  | neg  | neu  |
+----+----------------------+------------+-------+------+------+------+
|  1 | Test Search Title 2  | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  3 | Test Search Title 3  | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 35 | Test Search Title 11 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 38 | Test Search Title 12 | 2017-12-20 | 17    | 6    | 7    | 4    |
| 38 | Test Search Title 13 | 2017-12-21 | 3     | 6    | 7    | 4    |
| 40 | Test Search Title 14 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 41 | Test Search Title 15 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 51 | Test Search Title 16 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 52 | Test Search Title 17 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 53 | Test Search Title 18 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 57 | Test Search Title 19 | 2017-08-02 | 1     | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 57 | Test Search Title 20 | 2017-08-06 | 1     | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 57 | Test Search Title 21 | 2017-12-20 | 4     | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 58 | Test Search Title 22 | 2017-12-03 | 1     | NULL | NULL | 1    |
| 60 | Test Search Title 23 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 61 | Test Search Title 24 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 62 | Test Search Title 25 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 63 | Test Search Title 26 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 64 | Test Search Title 27 | 2017-12-21 | 133   | 39   | 41   | 53   |
| 67 | Test Search Title 28 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 69 | Test Search Title 29 | 2017-12-12 | 1     | 3    | 1    | NULL |
| 69 | Test Search Title 30 | 2017-12-17 | 3     | 3    | 1    | NULL |
| 69 | Test Search Title 31 | 2017-12-18 | 1     | 3    | 1    | NULL |
| 70 | Test Search Title 32 | 2017-12-12 | 1     | NULL | 3    | 1    |
| 70 | Test Search Title 33 | 2017-12-17 | 3     | NULL | 3    | 1    |
| 70 | Test Search Title 34 | 2017-12-18 | 1     | NULL | 3    | 1    |
| 73 | Test Search Title 35 | 2017-12-17 | 3     | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 74 | Test Search Title 36 | 2013-10-06 | 1     | 1    | 1    | 1    |
+----+----------------------+------------+-------+------+------+------+
```

It's giving null days if no results , null totals and wrong counting.
The main problem is wrong counting.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for all of this. You can just use `CASE` like this:

```
select
  DATE(r.published_at) as day,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'negative' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Negative,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Positive,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'neutral' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Neutral,
  COUNT(r.id) AS Total
from results as r
left join queries q ON q.id = r.query_id
GROUP BY DATE(r.published_at);
```

This will give you the status count and total count for each day.

**Note that:** I used the table `Results` as the left table so that I got all the days even if there are no results in the queries table. This is just up to you depending on your data. This way you were getting null days in your first query because your results table was the right table with left join.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e84b00/4)**:

```
|        day | Negative | Positive | Neutral | Total |
|------------|----------|----------|---------|-------|
| 2017-11-27 |        1 |        0 |       0 |     1 |
| 2017-12-20 |        2 |        2 |       0 |     4 |
```

---

If you want to get the counts for each question and for each day, add the id and title to the group by like this:

```
select
  q.id, q.title,
  DATE(r.published_at) as day,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'negative' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Negative,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Positive,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'neutral' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Neutral,
  COUNT(r.*) AS Total
from queries q
left join results as r ON q.id = r.query_id
WHERE q.history=0
GROUP BY q.id, q.title, DATE(r.published_at)
```